# Is there any way to split GIF image into frames and save it as JPEG or PNG in Android

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm working with GIFs in my Android Project and at this stage I've to grab frames of particular GIF and save it as JPEG or PNG into the device.
I've tried Glide but nothing is working.
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: `I've tried Glide` could you share your code of what you have tried? `but nothing is working.` please leave out information that's incorrect. It's impossible that you have tried 'everything'. If you really did try everything then you wouldn't be asking this question. Also, have you done any research, like googling "Convert gif to png"?

Comment: Answer my questions

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you Try this code [Link](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/4479231)